# Prove an equivalent condition to Lebesgue integrability

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

> Let $f$ be a non-negative, measurable, real-valued function defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$. Show that $f$ is Lebesgue integrable on $\mathbb{R}$ if and only if the series $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}km(E_k)$ converges, where $E_k = \{x|k\le f(x)<k+1\}$ and $m$ denotes Lebesgue measure.

The direction $(\implies)$ is simply done by countable additivity of integration, since $E_k$'s are pairwise disjoint and we can write 
$$\infty>\int_{\mathbb{R}} f = \sum_{k\ge0}\int_{E_k}f\ge \sum_{k\ge0}km(E_k). $$
Hence the convergence of the series.

But I was stuck on the opposite direction and need some help. Thanks!

Comment: What about the case $f(x) = \frac{1}{x} \chi_{[1, \infty)}(x)$ in which case $m(E_0) = \infty$, $m(E_1) = m(E_2) = \cdots = 0$ but $f$ is not $L^1$?

Comment: @DanielSchepler Thanks for the comment. So you're saying that this is one example implying the series diverges, but  $f\notin L^1$? But this is the same as saying that f is $L^1$ then the series converges, right? I guess you were trying to give a counter example...

Comment: No, the series converges since the measure theory convention, especially in cases like this, is $0 \cdot \infty = 0$.  (But on the other hand, if you count that as divergent, then $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2} \chi_{[1, \infty)}(x)$ would form a counterexample to the forward direction with the same $m(E_k)$.)

Comment: @DanielSchepler Oh, I see. So the statement is actually false. They are not equivalent at all. But if we take the convention $0\cdot\infty=0$, then is the above proof for the forward direction correct?

Comment: Yes, it looks fine.  (If you like, you could argue that with that convention, $\sum_{k=0}^\infty k m(E_k) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty k m(E_k)$, and integrability certainly implies that $m(E_1), m(E_2), \ldots$ are all finite.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Cool. So the statement only holds for only one direction which depends on what convention one chooses. It makes a lot more sense to me. Thank you very much!

Comment: I think a correct statement could go something like: if $F_k = \{ x \mid \frac{1}{k+1} < f(x) \le \frac{1}{k} \}$, then $f$ is Lebesgue integrable if and only if $\sum_{k=1}^\infty k m(E_k)$ and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k} m(F_k)$ are both convergent.  (In other words, there are two main concerns for integrability: that not too much of a function is "large", and that how much of a function is "small" increases sufficiently slowly.)